# mysql: like operators find exact match

Tags: mysql

How to write a query to find exact word from below desc

I have recharge my vodafone prepaid mobile.

```
select * from user_details where ur_dt like 'vodafone'
```

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: I have a description.I have recharge my vodafone prepaid mobile.i want to find whether vodafone (exact word) contains in a table or not..not vodafones,not vodafoneprepaid

Answer (score 4):

Use `=` operator but not `like` for comparing exact match.

```
select * from user_details where ur_dt = 'vodafone'
```

And for a partial match use `like` with `%` denoting a partial search.

```
select * from user_details where ur_dt like '%vodafone%'
```

Note: As per documentation on [***`LIKE`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

`Like` causes a char based comparison. If there exists `'vodafone'` and you make a `like 'vodafone '` the result would be a `false`. But `'vodafone' = 'vodafone '` returns a `true`.

Comment: thanks but my requirement is different. I have a description like I have recharge my vodafone prepaid mobile.i want to find whether vodafone (exact word) contains in a row or not..not vodafones,not vodafoneprepaid

Comment: `Like` causes a char based comparison. If there exists `'vf'` and you make a `like 'vf '` the result would be a `false`. But `'vf' = 'vf '` returns a `true`.

Comment: select * from user_details where ur_dt = 'vodafone'  select * from user_details where ur_dt like '%vodafone%' neither works,what will u suggest.i am trying to find exact word

Comment: The second results other matches as well like `xyz-vodafone-mbl` etc. along with the exact matches.

Comment: What does the table have in `ur_dt` column? So that I can suggest an alternative.

Comment: ut_dt contains description of complaint like idea customer care number..i am trying to find exact idea word

Comment: given service of my Elantra inverter,
I have purchased a plot of 239 sq yard in ansal ,
I booked honda dio in Vishnu 
need to find below words only 
Elantra ,ansal,honda

Comment: Ok, then use multiple `ur_dt like '%elantra%' or ur_dt like '%ansal%' or ur_dt like '%honda%'` in where clause.

Comment: May be what you posted here as example is from 3 records. But you still need a wild card `'%'` search only in case if the field holds a set of words as sentence but not as a single word.

Comment: suppose hondaactive in description ,then it will also show..but i need exact honda word

Comment: Read my just previous comment. If a sentence contains other words in which you are not interested in then you have to include a `not like` in the where clause.

Comment: select * from user_details where ur_dt like '%vodafone%' where ur_dt not like '%vodafone' and  ur_dt not like 'vodafone%'

Comment: No. In the `not like` use other words in which you are not interested to fetch. say `ur_dt like '%honda%' and ( ur_dt not like '%activa%' or ur_dt not like '%dio%' )`